# Pass and return I/O stream by reference in overloaded I/O operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
class Distance {
   private:
      int feet;             
      int inches;          
      
   public:
      // required constructors
      Distance() {
         feet = 0;
         inches = 0;
      }
      Distance(int f, int i) {
         feet = f;
         inches = i;
      }
      friend ostream &operator<<( ostream &output, const Distance &D ) { 
         output << "F : " << D.feet << " I : " << D.inches;
         return output;            
      }

      friend istream &operator>>( istream  &input, Distance &D ) { 
         input >> D.feet >> D.inches;
         return input;            
      }
};
```

Why we need to input the reference of input and return the reference of input in overloaded operator of >>?
When I try to delete the ampersand in the parameter of input operator and return normal input, why the istream is still lost data after input D3.

```
friend istream &operator>>( istream  &input, Distance &D ) { 
         input >> D.feet >> D.inches;
         return input;            
      }
...
int main() {
   Distance D3;
   cin >> D3;//Input 4 5, data is not lost because pass by value???;
   cout << "Third Distance :" << D3 << endl;// Output 4 5
   int a=0;
   cin>>a;// Still require input data ????
   cout<<a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can found this article (by Onur Uzun) useful: https://medium.com/@nonuruzun/overloading-input-output-operators-in-c-a2a74c5dda8a

As he said there:

> "cout is an object of ostream class which is a compiler defined class.
> When we do cout<<obj where obj is an object of our class, the compiler
> first looks for an operator function in ostream, then it looks for a
> global function. One way to overload insertion operator is to modify
> ostream class which may not be a good idea. So we make a global method
> and if we want to allow them to access private data members of class,
> we must make them friend."

I hope that answer your question.

Comment: the question is why we have to pass by reference and return the reference variable of input??? In relation to friend function, I already understand it.

Comment: That is only to allow you to chain another >> after you return the istream object